# Firebase Rules - Nested ifs

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to do a few nested if statements to achieve that every user's email is verified befor he gets read write access.
But I dont know how to do that because if I write it in

```
"rules" : {
    "read" : "auth.token.email_verified",
    "write" : "auth.token.email_verified"
    "other_location" :{
        "read" : true, 
        "write": false
    }
}
```

The user will get write in other_location even through I set write to false in other_location.
I don't know why its like that but my simulation showed that.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase RTDB Rules [cascade from higher tiers down to the more specific ones](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authorization). If you allow the ability to perform read/write operations on a given key, which in your case is the root of your database, any key nested under that one will share the same allowed read/write permissions even if your nested rule says otherwise.

To overcome this, you can use [variables in the key's path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments) to match unnamed locations. By convention, these "other keys" variables are called `"$other"`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "restricted-location": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    },
    "$other": { // any key not named above at this level  
      ".read": "auth.token.email_verified",
      ".write": "auth.token.email_verified"
    }
  }
}
```